# Windows 10 desktop IE shortcut always available with Offline File feature disabled

Tags: group-policy

**Context**

For Windows 10 laptops , that are joined to a Windows domain , offline files is disabled due to security reasons.
No files are allowed to be stored locally on the laptops, by the end user.
For same security reason access to C drive is also restricted for domain users. They only have access to drive mappings, that are avaible when connected to LAN/Domain.

Next to that, the user profile folders (desktop, documents, pictures etc.) are redirected to a central server, that is available through drive mapping when the laptop is connected to the Domain/LAN.

**Challenge**

When the laptop is offline (meaning offline from the domain/LAN), an Internet Explorer shortcut should be easily available however. For example on the desktop. This to enable the user to access an RDP server farm.
The challenge is to give the user access to the IE shortcut/URL when not connected to the LAN, and at the same time keep up with the security restrictions of User folder Redirection and Disallowing Offline Files.

**Options?**

What options are there to achieve the goals as described?

I have experimented with the GPO "Specify administratively assigned Offline Files".
Is it correct to say that the GPO "Specify administratively assigned Offline Files", only works when Offline Files is enabled, i.e. enabling the GPO "Allow or Disallow use of the Offline Files feature" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the shortcut to C:\Users\Public\Desktop, this is the "All users" desktop. The content of Public\Desktop is "merged" (the view is merged, the file is not copied) with the content of the users' profile.

About this: `Is it correct to say that the GPO "Specify administratively assigned Offline Files", only works when Offline Files is enabled` =>I don't know.

Comment: I have copied the shortcut to "C:\Users\Public\Desktop". 

When booting the laptop without connection to the mapped drive where the User Folders are redirected to, the desktop is empty. It only shows the Recycle Bin icon

Answer (score 0):

What did work was to add the shortcut to the All User's Start Menu in the GPO configuration.

The shortcut specifically needs this setting on the Common tab of the shortcut setting in the GPO to be turned off (unticked):
**" Run in logged on user's security context"**

The start menu item remains after reboot.

[gpo shortcut general tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRI2r.png)

[gpo shortcut common tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRD1V.png)